# Visual pixel-perfect selection in QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a `QGraphicsScene` where I want the user to draw/move things around. Currently I can draw all the shapes I want (namely [un]filled rectangles and ellipses, lines and cubic bezier curves), deriving `QGraphics*Item`.

I can also achieve selection on these items, but I'd like some sort of *pixel-perfect* selection. For example, a curve can be selected while clicking next to it where it is curved, even if the mouse's not on the real line. Same goes for empty rectangles or ellipses, clicking on the hole in the middle of them select them as well.

This is because of the way `contains` works, and it does not fit my needs : it basically checks if the point is in a bounding rect. `setBoundingRegionGranularity(1)` solves nothing (mentionning it just in case).

I also tried to check directly if the point is contained in the `QPainterPath` of my items but this gives me the same results.

**How can I have visual selection of my shapes ?**

The only solution I see at the moment would be reimplementing my own `contains` function for every shape I have, but this may be quite complicated and I'd really like to have this done by Qt if possible.

I'm using Python 3.3 and PyQt 5 (.1.1 IIRC) but that's more related to the Qt framework than the language/binding, and answers in C++ are fine too.

Answer (score 1):

`QGraphicsPathItem::shape` contains the path that it is displaying including its inner area. The behavior you expect is more like `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. If its `shapeMode` is `QGraphicsPixmapItem::MaskShape` (default), its shape will contain only opaque points. You may want to draw your curves on pixmaps and show that pixmaps in the scene and enjoy the default behavior. You can also redefine `QGraphicsPathItem::shape` and implement this behavior. Working example, C++ (can be easily adapted for Python):

```
class MyGraphicsPathItem : public QGraphicsPathItem {
public:
  MyGraphicsPathItem() {}
  QPainterPath shape() const {
    QRectF rect = path().boundingRect();
    QImage canvas(rect.size().toSize(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    canvas.fill(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    QPainter painter(&canvas);
    painter.setPen(pen());
    painter.drawPath(path().translated(-rect.topLeft()));
    painter.end();
    QPainterPath result;
    result.addRegion(QPixmap::fromImage(canvas).mask());
    return result.translated(rect.topLeft());
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
MyGraphicsPathItem* item = new MyGraphicsPathItem();
item->setPath(path);
item->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
item->setPen(QPen(Qt::green, 3));
scene->addItem(item);
```

Note that this implementation is quite slow. Use with caution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, using Pixmaps drops the antialiasing on the shapes, did I miss something ?

Comment: You need to enable `QPainter::Antialiasing` hint in the painter you use to create pixmap. If you use pixmap scaling, you should also set `QGraphicsPixmapItem::setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation)`.